.NET MAUI: System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'Gdip' threw an exception'
Upon debugging my Android .NET MAUI application I get the message on the app startup:
.NET MAUI: System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'Gdip' threw an exception'

and the app crashes. Call stack does not have any helpful info:

I do not use System.Drawing.Common in my application as it is not compatible.
How can I fix this issue?

In your MAUI Application project, at the project root level add the file runtimeconfig.template.json.

the file should contain this json:
{
  "configProperties": {
    "System.Drawing.EnableUnixSupport": true
  }
}

After that clean and rebuild the project.
